# How should I implement sub-windows in my OpenGL viewport?

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

How should I implement sub-windows in my OpenGL viewport?  Inside my viewport, I want to reserve some space on the left for labels, and some space around the edges as a border.  I've got all the coordinates figured out and everything is displaying properly.  My problem is clipping the things in one subwindow that are spilling over into the others.  I can't seem to figure out what the OpenGL 3.3, core context way of doing things is.  Is it to

- use per-vertex clipping?
- a scissor test?
- a stencil test?
- associate a framebuffer with different parts of my window?

Which commands should I be looking at?

Comment: Use `glViewport (...)` to restrict the region of your framebuffer where geometry is projected onto. Scissoring or stenciling part of the screen away would be less efficient and you would be losing information - kind of like the zoom picture mode on TVs. Per-vertex clipping would not help either, you need to do clipping at the primitive level to do something like this.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Thank you for your answer, but are you sure that will clip?  http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/142880-glViewPort-doesn-t-clip

Comment: Of course it will not clip anything, the viewport mapping happens ***after*** clipping. Clipping is defined mostly by your projection matrix, the viewport just defines the region of the screen in which the geometry that was clipped is rasterized into. To oversimplify this, it defines how the ***already*** clipped geometry is stretched to fill your screen.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Sorry, I'm actually displaying everything fine.  My problem is actually the clipping. I will make my question clearer.

Comment: I would still suggest using a different projection matrix and viewport for each of your sub-windows. This is because in newer versions of GL, you can have viewport arrays for use in the geometry shader. Sub-windows are really easy to implement that way, and you don't have to worry about stencil testing or scissoring because if you setup the projection matrix properly for each sub-window, clipping will be done already.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Thanks Andon, that sounds great.  Could you add an answer for the sake of others?  And would you mind mentioning the names of the commands I will be calling to set up the "viewport arrays"?  Is it glViewport?  something else?  This solution will clip things, right?

Comment: Actually, it is more along the lines of: `glViewportArrayv (...)` and `glViewportIndexed (...)`. I will submit a mock-up of the sub-windows you have described as a temporary answer, let me know if that is what you are trying to achieve and I will explain how to setup the projection matrix / viewport for each subwindow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I spend time writing a full answer, I would like you to confirm that this is what you were describing in your original question:

```
*---------------------------------------*
| ------------------------------------- |
| |   |                               | |
| |   |                               | |
| |   |                               | |
|C| A |              B                |C|
| |   |                               | |
| |   |                               | |
| |___|_______________________________| |
*---------------------------------------*

A = Labels
B = Main Window
C = Border
```

Comment: Yes, that's it.  But I have no problems setting up the matrices myself.  My problem is that when I draw into B, it spills over into A and C, and I need to clip that output.

Comment: Also, please don't worry about the border, as I think it might complicate your solution — just figuring out how to separate A and B will be more than kind enough  to getting me on my way to implementing this.  Thank you.

Comment: To be clear, you are using a projection matrix with the bounds of sub-window B when you draw into B? Clipping is broken if this is the case. The way clipping works in OpenGL, is that if after projection any vertex in a primitive has a coordinate that is > Clip.W or < -Clip.W the offending edge(s) is/are clipped. Have a look at [***this page***](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html) for more details, and ignore the term `viewport` in the diagram (this diagram only works if you assume that the viewport has the same dimensions as the projection matrix).

Comment: In this example, lets suppose B has a width of 100 and a height of 30. You could use an orthographic projection matrix with left=0,right=100,top=0,bottom=30. Now, let us suppose that sub-window B's origin with respect to the ***entire*** parent window (outlined by C) is at 50,20. You would use `glViewport (...)` with X=50,Y=20,height=30,width=100. Anything you draw into sub-window B would be relative to the window's origin and not the entire window. So for each sub-window, you have your own coordinate system.

Comment: Yes, that will clip anything that is outside the bounds of the projection matrix.

Comment: I think `glViewportArrayv` was only added in 4.1, so I'll have to stick to `glViewport` though, right?

Comment: Yes, that was not really relevant to this question. But it is the reason I prefer to think in terms of projection matrix / viewport for each window rather than using scissor rectangles or setting up a stencil buffer (but this could be useful if you wanted non-rectangular windows). The interesting thing about viewport arrays is that you can render an object once and then using a geometry shader spit out several different views to different locations on screen - it is useful for modeling software that often embeds views of the same model down different axes into a single window.